# File creation works on command line, but not in bash script

Tags: bash, web

I wrote a small script to grab the headers for all websites in a given file. The script reads every line, and the command that it repeats for every line works when run on it's own. For some reason, when I run this script, I get an error that says "Warning: Failed to create file (filename): no such file or directory" for every iteration of the loop. I know it's probably some kind of a syntax error, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated! The script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    curl -X GET -i $line -o $line.txt;
done < $1
```

Comment: What's the value of `line`? You might need to use `--create-dirs` as well.

Comment: the line variable represents the content of one line in the text file being given to the script. In this case in particular, it's a url

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: So it contains a `/`? I'm not interested in what it represents, only in the exact characters in the value when the error occurs. `http://example.com/foo.html`, for example, is *not* a valid file name.

Comment: I think that may be the issue. Thanks!